# Why mmap and not pread/pwrite for accessing /dev/mem

Tags: memory, mmap

When attempting to access the physical memory through a known address, e.g. memory mapped PCI configuration space, once the address is calculated, why is it not possible to use pread/pwrite to access that location as a simple offset from memory address zero? Why do we have to mmap it and use pointer arithmetic to access?

A similar access to /dev/cpu/*/msr is possible using pread/pwrite